# Como mejorar el rendimiento de consulta linq? .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Actualmente realizo una consulta a una BD de sql server mediante linq al realizar la consulta le paso en los parámetros para realizar búsqueda. Le mando un arreglo de Id's y que la fecha sea mayor o igual a el 1 de enero del 2020. Esta consulta va y busca y  me trae el historial de incapacidades , fecha inicio de incapacidades y fecha final así como los días de incapacidades que le asignaron. mi problema viene cuando realizo una **consulta con mas de 3000 id's(numeros de nomina)** para buscar tarda demaciado en obtener los datos al rededor de **40 seg.** o mas, me podrian ayudar en como optimizar la consulta?

Este es un fragmento de mi consulta como la tengo actualmente:

```
 public List<P_Incapacidad> ListaIncapacidad(int?[] nomina)
    {
        List<P_Incapacidad> l = new List<P_Incapacidad>();
        try
        {
            l.AddRange(dbClinica.P_Incapacidad.ToList().Where(x => 
            nomina.Contains(x.NUMNOMINA)
            && x.FECHAINICIO >= Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2020")));
            //l = l.Where(x=> Convert.ToDateTime(x.FECHAINICIO.ToString()).Year >= 2020).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorLog(ex.Message);
            return l;
        }
        return l;
    }
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema de rendimiento está aquí:

```
dbClinica.P_Incapacidad.ToList()
```

Al llamar a `ToList()` se crea una lista con todos los registros de la tabla y después se aplican los filtros.

La solución es llamar `ToList()` de último.

```
l.AddRange(dbClinica.P_Incapacidad
    .Where(x => nomina.Contains(x.NUMNOMINA)
    && x.FECHAINICIO >= Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2020"))
    .ToList());
```